# passing multiple parameters to stored procedure using .netCore

Tags: c#

Im not sure if im doing it right or not passing multiple params to my SP, because it gives me an error that the function does not exist,here is my function in postgressql:

```
SELECT wpv.avail_pro_failedbattry_error_powerconv(
    <date>,
    <date>,
    <character varying>,
    <character varying>,
    <character varying>
);
```

here is my .NetCore part:

```
     regionalManager = "%";
            dtFrom = "02/07/2020";
            dtTo = "03/07/2020";
            string service_under = "%";
            string supervisor = "%";
            NpgsqlParameter p0 = new NpgsqlParameter("@drfrom", NpgsqlDbType.Date);
            NpgsqlParameter p1 = new NpgsqlParameter("@dtto", NpgsqlDbType.Date);
            NpgsqlParameter p2 = new NpgsqlParameter("@regionalmanager", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);
            NpgsqlParameter p3 = new NpgsqlParameter("@serviceunder", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);
            NpgsqlParameter p4 = new NpgsqlParameter("@supervisor", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);
            var x = _db.dataInGlance.FromSqlRaw(@"SELECT * from wpv.avail_pro_failedbattry_error_powerconv(@p0,@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4)
                                res (o_availability double precision, o_production double precision,o_numberofturbines integer, o_errors_disabled integer,o_failed_battery integer,o_power integer,o_crew_present text)",dtFrom,dtTo,regionalManager,service_under,supervisor);
```

passing params like this is the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass paramters with simple string interpolation eg:

```
var x = _db.dataInGlance.FromSqlRaw($@"
SELECT * from wpv.avail_pro_failedbattry_error_powerconv(
'{dtFrom.ToString(""yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"")}',
'{dtTo.ToString(""yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"")}',
'{regionalManager}',
'{service_under}',
'{supervisor}')
...
```

You will probably need to setup special format for date variables for your languageCulture.

To send parameters you have to use names you specified as 1st parameter, like `@drfrom`, "@dtto" etc.

```
var x = _db.dataInGlance.FromSqlRaw(@"
SELECT * from wpv.avail_pro_failedbattry_error_powerconv(
@drfrom,
@dtto,
@regionalmanager,
@serviceunder,
@supervisor)
...
```

There also an option to send it like

```
\set p1 @drfrom
\set p2 @dtto
\set p3 @regionalmanager
\set p4 @serviceunder
\set p5 @supervisor

var x = _db.dataInGlance.FromSqlRaw(@"
SELECT * from wpv.avail_pro_failedbattry_error_powerconv(
:p1, :p2, :p3, :p4, :p5)
...
```

Comment: whats the diffrence between this approach and ngpsql parameter?and how should i pass if i want to use npgsql params?

Comment: I believe you can indeed use string interpolation with EF Core to get it to automagically parametrise your query. But there are apparently [gotchas to be aware of](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) if you want to avoid exposing yourself for SQL injection attacks